# Need to use a password in package.json

Tags: npm

When working locally I start my application with an npm command in my package.json. The problem is that I need this command to include a password for a remote database:

```
"scripts": {
        "start":
            "MONGO_URL='mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@URL:PORT/DB-NAME' meteor --settings settings.json"
    },
```

This is working but I dont want to save my password to my source control. How can I run the same command without committing my password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the environement variable programmaticaly at startup and store the secret in the `settings.json` file (which is appropriate to store secrets and shouldn't be in version control - [see here](https://guide.meteor.com/deployment.html#environment))

in the `startup/server/index.js` file:

```
let mongoPassword = Meteor.settings.private.mongoPassword;
process.env.MONGO_URL = "mongodb://USERNAME:" + mongoPassword + "@URL:PORT/DB-NAME";
```

You can also choose to start your app using the `meteor` command and store the `MONGO_URL` environment variable in your local development environment

In production, you shouldn't use the `meteor` command but build with `meteor build` and then run the bundled app with `node main.js`